# Does Microsoft Excel file save every update date information?

Tags: excel

I need to check an excel file is updated daily. I cannot base on the content of the excel file to determine whether it has been updated daily.

I want to know whether excel will have a "save log" to save when the file was updated?

Comment: How is the Excel file being updated or created? Could you check the last modified timestamp?

Comment: I receive a 2 years old file. I need to check whether the data in the file were created and updated across the last two years, so I cannot just check the last update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Excel does NOT keep track of saving history. If your specific Excel spreadsheet has a VBA script that does make a log then you will have the history. Otherwise: bad luck.

In case the file sits on a network drive that gets backed up every so often, you could alternatively consult the back ups of the network drive, if the IT department allows you.

Final alternative for verifying if the process was followed at all is to have a second source and check parts or all of your excel file with that source. However if you would have a complete source you wouldnt need the excel... But a partial check could give you enough confidence, especially when you see certain values NOT matching, then you know for sure the process wasn't always followed.